# DataGrip is not providing intellisense support

Tags: sql-server, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

DataGrip from JetBrains is not providing Intellisense for Cross Database queries.

```
use mydb;
select * from otherdb.dbo.
```

using MSSQL

Comment: It should work. Is this database in the DB-tree?

Comment: Yes the Database is in DB tree

Comment: Can you please attach a screenshot?

Comment: I think I figured out the problem, we have to right click on DB in DB tree and select synchronize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leaving it for who seems to be struggling with this
1) while creating connection create without selecting DB.
2) In DB tree select click more Schemas and select DBs you want for cross querying.
3) Right click on those DBs and select synchronize

now cross DB should be working.

Answer (score 4):

I came across this question in search of a solution to troubleshooting intellisense in DataGrip. The accepted answer didn't go quite far enough for my use case, see below for my solution:

A similar issue was posted to IntelliJ's community forms [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000191404-DataGrip-Intellisense-sometimes-it-works-sometimes-it-doesn-t).

This answer relates to DataGrip 2017.1.5 (is likely applicable to other versions as well):

1. After creating the initial connection to your server, open the Database tool window using:

   - (ALT + F1) or
   - (View -> Tool Windows -> Database).
2. Listed beneath your server connection you will see a "Schemas..." item, double click it. This will expand into a list of all DB schemas you have access to on that server.
3. Select the schemas you are interested in, and additionally expand each DB schema to select all child schemas for that DB.
4. Click the refresh button in the schema selection window to synchronize your settings (two arrows pointing at each other in a circle).

   - [Image of Database Toolbar with DB/Schema selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLbgW.png)

Comment: Thanks, that works! I think the shortcut is ALT + 1 and not F1 at least in Windows 11.